# After migrating Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3, I get all tabs names on products as Migration_xxxx

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I've migrated my Magento to 2.3, and I'm getting my products tabs like this:

Migration_Meta Information
Migration_recurring Profile
Migration_Design
Migration_Gift Option

Is this right or did something go bad in my migration? If so what should I do for fixing it, removing those tables?

Comment: By what way did you migrate your data from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3?

Comment: Hello, i migrate using migrationtool from magento